# Passing variables from PHP to PERL

Tags: php, perl

i have written this program to pass a variable in the embedded perl script but it gives blank output :-( why it is not working. Please fix this problem.

the php script

```
<?php
$var1='high'; 
exec('C:/xampp/htdocs/WORK/hello.pl'.' '.EscapeShellArg("$var1"),$output);
echo ($output);
?>
```

the perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

    $var1=<>; 

    print $var1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your *.pl files are executable? Try to execute hello.pl from the command line, without php

Comment: yes i did.... its executing without any error

Comment: Ok, recreated it locally. `shift` does work, and `<>` not. Im not sure why it this way, but.. You have to use either `shift` or `$ARGV[0]` to get the value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745623/why-should-i-use-argv-or-instead-of-stdin-in-perl - so.. <STDIN> is only for piping, for arguments you have to use ARGV

Comment: Thankyou @VitalyDyatlov i got the output :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
 $var1 = shift;
```

rather than reading the value from standard input or argument files?

Comment: i want to take the input as a string, instead of an array

Comment: @user1083096: OK. But let's process step by step. By now, you are not taking it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Because youre trying to send an array as a string... Youll have to serialize the array into a string that perl can deserialize, like `JSON`, `XML`, `CSV`, etc..

Comment: No, because "$var1" becomes "Array" (raw command is like this: C:/xampp/htdocs/WORK/hello.pl "Array" ) and there should be the output anyway. Issues somewhere else

Comment: Thats true... kinda jumped the gun... regardless hes not going to get the result hes expecting, though he needs to get the var passing correct first.

Comment: sorry, i m new to this field.... could you please tell me where is the problem actually..

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that [EscapeShellArg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) expects the $arg parameter to be of type string, while, in your case, it's an array...

Comment: Actually at that point he should be sending the string representation of the array i think because hes got it in double quotes when he passes it...

Comment: i changed "$var1" to '$var1' but its not working :(

Comment: Are you able to call the PERL script via command line? Does it produce the expected output? Could we get a sample of the parameters that you are using when calling the script and the output that it produces?

Comment: yes i m able to call the script and it does produces the output. i tried using the same script posted above and its printing "array" as the output.