# Passing session variables from php to perl

Tags: php, perl, post, cookies, cgi

I need to pass php session variables from my php form to a perl script and vice versa so the forms fields can keep their values.

form.php

```
<?php  session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $post_arr = $_POST;

    $expire = 8*3600; 
    setcookie("Cookie_Info", serialize($post_arr), time()+$expire); 
   }

if (isset($_COOKIE['Cookie_Info'])) {
    $data = unserialize($_COOKIE['Cookie_Info']);
} else {
    $data = array(
          'from' => '',
              'area_html' => ''
    );

        }
```

.....

```
<form name="sendForm" method="post" action="test.cgi" >
<tr><td> from: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="from" value="<?php echo $data->from; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

My question is how could i do it in the perl side

Comment: ...and what's your question?

Comment: my question is how can i do it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, in the perl side :

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;         
use CGI::Cookie;
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->parse($ENV{COOKIE});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you searched already? I don't think so...

[Passing variables from PHP to PERL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798478/passing-variables-from-php-to-perl)

You need to use exec:

```
<?php
$var1='high'; 
exec('C:/xampp/htdocs/WORK/hello.pl'.' '.EscapeShellArg("$var1"),$output);
echo ($output);
?>
```

Other link:

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/passing-arrays-from-php-to-a-perl-script-run-as-35600.html

Comment: I searched already, i can pass variables from php to perl, it is not my question, my question is how to pass cookies/sessions variables...